# libcaffe.so.1.0.0-rc3 not found

Tags: caffe, pycaffe, machine-code

i am new in caffe.i am trying to install caffe on my ubontu 14.4 flowing https://chunml.github.io/ChunML.github.io/project/Installing-Caffe-CPU-Only/
tutorial but when i run the commend make all i get the error

```
AR -o .build_release/lib/libcaffe.a
LD -o .build_release/lib/libcaffe.so.1.0.0-rc5
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_imgcodecs
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so.1.0.0-rc5] Error 1
```

i can not understand why i am facing this. i googled a lot to fix this problem but got no solution. can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

The liker didn't find opencv_imgcodecs library in your system. Make sure that opencv is correctly installed. If it is, add the library location to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and run `ldconfig`.
In summary, run:

```
sudo updatedb
locate libopencv_imgcodecs.so
```

Found?  if not, install opencv.  if yes, run:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=<library location>:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
sudo ldconfig
```

and then run `make` again.